# GNUplot: drawing color map from file

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap, colormap

I am dealing with a color map but I encounter some problem. Here is my code:

```
set size 1,1; set origin 0,0
set grid layerdefault
set xlabel "x (rdaius)"
set ylabel "z (radius)"

set sample 11; set isosamples 11
set pm3d map
set palette
set colorbox
set lmargin 0


set pm3d flush begin
splot 'density.txt' u 1:2:3
```

However, there is error message:

> Warning: Single isoline (scan) is not enough for a pm3d plot.

How can fix the problem?

Also, I tried using `plot 'density.txt' u 1:2:3 with image`, there is also error message:

> Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid. N = 36759  K = 201

**Note**
The data file `density.txt` is formatted as

```
  X       Y      N Part.
=====   =====    =====
-10.0   -10.0     10.0
-10.0    -9.9     324.0
-10.0    -9.8     256.5
-10.0    -9.7     0.0
-10.0    -9.6     32.5
-10.0    -9.5     7.8
-10.0    -9.4     66.4
 ...      ...      ...
```

Where x and y ranges from -10 to 10, N. Part ranges from 0.0 to ~1000.0.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find this anywhere, what does N and K mean for the heatmap plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a blank line after before you increment values in your first dimension:

```
#data.dat
<x1> <y1> <z11>
<x1> <y2> <z12>
<x1> <y3> <z13>
<x1> <y4> <z14>

<x2> <y1> <z21>
<x2> <y2> <z22>
<x2> <y3> <z23>
<x2> <y4> <z24>

...

<xn> <y1> <zn1>
<xn> <y2> <zn2>
<xn> <y3> <zn3>
<xn> <y4> <zn4>
```

You'll also need to skip over your headers with `splot 'data.dat' every ::2 ...`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! After I follow your suggestion, the warning message gone; but the plot is still empty (the grid, color bar and axis is normal). I cannot figure out why the figure is still empty.

Comment: Are you using `splot ... with pm3d` ?

Comment: Uh, I found what's going wrong. I didn't notice that I left 2 blank lines so that it can not process successfully. Thanks!